# Find the value of a text box in Unity with c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my game that I'm creating I have a textbox that has the value of the amount of lives the character has. I want to know how to check that value so I can then use that data to change scenes, for example: if the text box is five and going down I want to check when (lives = 0); then to change the scene. Also, if anyone knows the code to change scenes that would be very helpful.

Comment: You should store this value in a variable that you can perform logic on. The text box should only be for display purposes. Use the variable that sets that display for what you want to do here.

Comment: I know, but I'm new to unity, and my partner on the project implemented the system, so I don't know how to switch it or create a new system, but is there a way to check the value of the text box string to then change scenes with?

Answer (score 0):

You should just keep a variable with the number of lives so you don't have to fetch it from a text box or any other element. When the game starts, set `lives = 5`. Then each time the user dies, decrease this variable by 1.

The textbox (or better yet just a static label) should only be used for display, not for retrieval. Make sure to keep the variable available so you can use it directly to decide when the game is over.

Comment: but do you know if there is a way to check the value of the text box?